# Ajax is not working in wordpress admin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

iam a beginner level wordpress developer ..now at halfway on creating newsletter plugin administration panel. In this admin panel iam using jquery.post ajax for submitting the form.Unfortunately the ajax is not working. But i am using the same wordpress ajax in my site's front end for taking email id from users and it's working fine.

i have verified all the code..unfortunately i couldn't  find what's wrong in my code.

**my jquery script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  

   jQuery("#saveValue").click(function(){
       jQuery("#apiData").submit();

   });


   jQuery("#apiData").submit(adminSettingSave('#apiData'));

});

function adminSettingSave(secti){
    return function(){
        var form_data = jQuery(secti).serialize();
        form_data += '&action=settings-save';
        alert(secti);
         jQuery.post(ajaxurl, form_data, function (response) {
             alert(response);

         });



    }
}
```

**wordpress function**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_settings-save', 'settings_save');
function settings_save()
{

    die();
}
```

but this is not working, instead of this its reloading the page
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about change

```
 jQuery("#apiData").submit(adminSettingSave('#apiData'));
```

to

```
 jQuery("#apiData").submit(function() {adminSettingSave('#apiData'); return false});
```

I think your page reload because your submit event initialization do not work. The submit event listener function also need returning false to prevent default form action.